# Sub-dependency incompatible with node version, how to find and pin last good version

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to install the dependencies of a nodejs project via `npm install` (or yarn). However, it pulls in some sub-dependencies that are not compatible with my node version:

```
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for lib0@0.2.78: wanted: {"node":">=16"} (current: {"node":"14.17.4","npm":"6.14.14"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: lib0@0.2.78
```

My `package.json` uses the hat for all dependencies, so it should allow minor or patch version changes:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@jupyterlab/application": "^3.1.0",
  "@jupyterlab/coreutils": "^5.1.0",
  "@jupyterlab/services": "^6.1.0"
}
```

Is there any way to a) pin the offending sub-sub-dependency to the last working version? Or to b) add a global constraint to say "only go as far as everything is compatible with node 14"? I think NPM doesn't allow constraints that way.

Alternatively c) is there a (systematic, easy) way to figure out which direct dependency starts to pull in the offending package? Then I might be able to pin it - but if the direct dependencies are also lax in their dependencies it might pull it in anyway.

(I'm aware that node 14 is EOL, but it would be helpful to get this running somehow, in order to have a base before upgrading to a newer release).